# Help in a formual field for workflow rule criteria

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow, contracts

I have a requirement ,where certain conditions should get met for an email notification to go the owner before 100 days of the contract end date.
So i have created the a time based workflow rule and a email alert.

Condition is 1:

1)Renewable status is equal to pipeline , next qtr

2)Next Year Status is not equal to renewed or renewed lost.

3)Renewed is true

So while creating a Rule criteria i have used the filter as :
This is the Criteria met conditions i have given for 100 days .

```
((Contract: Contract End DateNOT EQUAL TOnull) AND (Contract: Renewal StatusEQUALS pipeline) ) OR (Contract: Renewal StatusEQUALS next qtr) OR (Contract: Next Year  Status NOT EQUAL TO Renewed) OR (Contract: Next Quarter Renewal StatusNOT EQUAL TO Renewed lost)
```

Now when the 100 days email is sent to the owner ,their is an update done for the field SRR (picklist).

a)If SRR is YES --- then an email notification is sent for 15 /30/45 days .

b)If SRR is No ---- then stop sending email

c)If SRR --not updated with any value and left blank .

Then i need to send an email notification for 90 days before the contract end date to the owner.

1)Renewable status is equal to pipeline , next qtr --picklist field

2)Next Year Status is not equal to renewed or renewed lost.---picklist field
3)Renewed is true ---formula field make it checked

4)SRR is Blank(not updated)  ---picklist field.

NOw if the SRR field is YES and 15 /30 /45 days email to be sent .
If SRR is NO or Blank --stop sending the email.

How do i add the 3 & 4 Condition in the formula field.

Formula used is rule criteria:

```
AND( 
OR( 
ISPICKVAL(Renewable status, 'next qtr'), 
ISPICKVAL(Renewable status, 'pipeline') 
), 
NOT(ISPICKVAL(Next Year Status, 'renewed' )), 
NOT(ISPICKVAL(Next Year Status, 'renewed lost')) 
)
```

Can u let me know which one is better writing a criteria condition or Formula evaluated true .
Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: There is no better between writing formula or using criteria.  They are equivalent, you can just do more w formulas and typically need them for more complex logic.  If you need help w the formula I can try, please elaborate on what "srr is null for 90 days" means - is "null for 90 days" the picklist value?

Comment: One advantage to formulas is you can comment them with `/* .. */`

Comment: @gorav,@cropredy:Thanks for the response.I have updated the post .Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one rule with two time triggers.

First, include the criteria w AND logic

```
ISBLANK(TEXT(SRR))
```

Then create two time triggers with send email actions on both

```
TT1: 100 days before contract end date
action: send email

TT2: 90 days before contract end date
action: send email
```

100 days before end date, SRR is blank and email will send.

If, after the 100 day alert, SRR is updated (by user) to yes / no, then the rule will no longer meet the criteria and the 90 day alert will not send.

If SRR remains blank, the 90 day alert will send.

You will need a separate rule that sends the 15/30/45 day alert if SRR = YES.

Note that you could alternatively build this all in one process using process builder.  I still prefer workflow rules as I feel the bulkification on workflows is still more robust than process builder but this will eventually be resolved.